# Start Animation repeatedly every minutes in android app

Tags: java, android, xml

I want my animation start repeatedly every 2 minutes in my android app, as my code it doesn't work. Please help on my code below. Thanks in advance.

```
 TableLayout = (TableLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.table01);

    slide_down = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_down);
    slide_up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_up);
    TableLayout.startAnimation(slide_down);
    slide_down.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            TableLayout.startAnimation(slide_up);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TableLayout = (TableLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.table01);

slide_down = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_down);
slide_up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_up);
TableLayout.startAnimation(slide_down);

slide_down.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        TableLayout.startAnimation(slide_up);
        slide_up.setStartOffset(2000);  // delay in ms
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});

slide_up.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        TableLayout.startAnimation(slide_down);
        slide_down.setStartOffset(2000);  // delay in ms
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

I hope it will work!

Comment: Hi Kharirul Alam Licon, Thanks for your answer, but it still doesn't work, the animation only start when we start thee app. Please help

Comment: Try by adding this line:

`slide_down.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);`

Answer (score 1):

Check out [repeating animation with Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788067/repeating-animation-with-timer)

I agree with the accepted answer that a `Handler` can be used with `postDelayed` and a `Runnable`

Comment: THanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Pls use:

```
   TimerTask slideDownTask= new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
              TableLayout.startAnimation(slide_down);
        });
    }};
    new Timer().schedule(slideDownTask, 0, 120000);
```

Comment: hi, pls see update, the first parameter in schedule is a Task, this task start animation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer